# Help with 2 questions my professor gave us

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

I was wondering how to solve these two proofs my professor put on the blackboard today. He said they were pretty easy but i'm still unsure how to prove them. ANy help would be greatly appreciated!

> *(i). Given any $r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the number $\sqrt{r}$ is unique in the sense that, if $x$ is a positive real number such that $x^2 = r$, then $x=\sqrt{r}$.*
>
> *(ii). If $r < 0$ there exists no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = r$.*

Comment: What system are you working in?  Are you starting with some properties or axioms of the real number system, or are you starting with a construction of the real numbers, or what?

Comment: For (i) assume there are two solutions $a,b$ s.t. $a^2=r$ and $b^2=r$ with $a\neq b$. Then either $a>b$ or $a<b$. Can you derive a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2=r$ and $y^2=r$, then $(x+y)(x-y)=0$, hence $x+y=0$ or $x-y=0$. The former is impossible if $x,y>0$ as then $x+y>0$ as well; the latter means $x=y$.

If $x\ge 0$ then $x\cdot x\ge 0\cdot x$, i.e. $x^2\ge 0$. If $x\le 0$ then $-x\ge 0$ and hence $x^2=(-x)^2\ge 0$. In no case it is possible to have $x<0$.